# Is there a reliable way to get unique identifier for iOS device in 2015?

Tags: ios, installation, udid

is there a reliable way to get unique identifier for iOS device in 2015 there will be the same even after reinstalling an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not and is it also against Apple policy.

Your best option is to save a unique identifier in the KeyChain, which will be saved there util the iOS device is completely cleared form the settings.

This will also fixe the issue where you actually identifying device and not users.